# Python Dynamic assigning of variable name that stores database query result

Tags: python, variables, dynamic

```
i=0
 while min<max:
   lower_limit= min
   upper_limit= max
   cur.execute("SELECT * FROM %s WHERE %s > %f" %(InputTable,SortingColumnName))
   **row_ + 'i'** = cursor.fetchall()
   min = upper_limit 
   i+=1
```

in the above example I have a requirement where I have to specify the variable name according to the i value, when i=0 I want the variable name to be row_0,when 1 row_1 and so on. Can someone help me on how to achieve this.

Comment: You should never do this. Use a list or a dictionary to store the values; dynamically created names, while possible, are virtually never a good idea.

Comment: What you describe is precisely why (back in the days of Basic and C), arrays were invented.  A common didactic to teach people to program back then would start with simple variable manipulation, then records ("see, store more than 1 variable in one structure, like e.g. ... a student!") which then led onto multiple structures ("now you want to store 2 students, now 3, ... oh dear what to do? Well, use an array! A structure storing repeating elements of the *same* type!") etc. So as Bryan said, you shouldn't do this. Use a list, or a dict, or some other datastructure.

Comment: Thanks guys.Yeah , I have used dictionary

Comment: It is always better idea to use dictionary to store dynamically obtained values